Vue js - Cannot find module '/app/node_modules/quasar/dist/transforms/import-transformation.js'
Today my npm run build suddenly failed, the error code was
Cannot find module '/app/node_modules/quasar/dist/transforms/import-transformation.js'
the weird thing is, yesterday my build was fine, but today suddenly it failed.
my package.json is as follows
,
  "dependencies": {
    "@mdi/font": "^7.2.96",
    "@quasar/extras": "^1.16.11",
    "apexcharts": "^3.44.0",
    "axios": "^0.27.2",
    "core-js": "^3.8.3",
    "encrypt-storage": "^2.12.16",
    "express": "^4.18.2",
    "fernet": "^0.4.0",
    "html2canvas": "^1.4.1",
    "jspdf": "^2.5.1",
    "moment": "^2.29.4",
    "node-polyfill-webpack-plugin": "^2.0.1",
    "pdf-viewer-vue": "^0.2.7",
    "pinia": "^2.1.4",
    "quasar": "^2.16.4",
    "register-service-worker": "^1.7.2",
    "roboto-fontface": "*",
    "sanitize-html": "^2.11.0",
    "stream": "^0.0.2",
    "sweetalert2": "^11.7.12",
    "vue": "^3.2.13",
    "vue-draggable-next": "^2.2.1",
    "vue-router": "^4.0.3",
    "vue3-apexcharts": "^1.4.4",
    "webfontloader": "^1.0.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.12.16",
    "@babel/eslint-parser": "^7.12.16",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-babel": "~5.0.0",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-eslint": "~5.0.0",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-pwa": "~5.0.0",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-router": "~5.0.0",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-vuex": "~5.0.0",
    "@vue/cli-service": "~5.0.0",
    "eslint": "^7.32.0",
    "eslint-plugin-vue": "^8.0.3",
    "sass": "^1.69.5",
    "sass-loader": "^12.0.0",
    "vue-cli-plugin-quasar": "~5.0.2",
    "vue-cli-plugin-vuetify": "~2.5.8",
    "vue-loader": "^17.2.2",
    "webpack-plugin-vuetify": "^2.0.0-alpha.0"
  }
}

i have tried from changing the quasar version, the quasar/extra version, remove package lock and node modules, reinstall it again. nothing have worked. I checked my last deployment on 1th may, it has the "import-transformation.js'" so my conclusion is today that file has gone missing. is there any changes i dont know about?

Removing lock file is a mistake, this is what guarantees reproducibility. The routine is to clear npm cache, remove node_modules but not lock file on reinstall. You can check with your eyes if import-transformation.js is there. You can see that it existed in 2.15 but was removed in 2.16 https://www.npmjs.com/package/quasar/v/2.15.4?activeTab=code .  I'm not sure why the module required if quasar version doesn't depend on it, error details were omitted, could come from plugins (vue-cli-plugin-quasar). You can try to downgrade to 2.15, especially because quasar was recently updated (2.16 is new)

Yeah, the thing is i was on 2.14.0, i thought something was depreceated or removed so i upgrade it to 2.16 thinking it might solve the issue. I just checked on npmjs, 2.14 should have the import-transform, but i have no idea why its missing on my machine.

You need to check with your eyes the contents of node_modules/quasar/dist/transforms/ to make conclusions if the error has reasons. In case you can reproduce the problem with  2.14  when cloning the project and installing the deps from scratch, please, provide it.

i just did a fresh install from 2.15.4 on docker, but the import-transformation is still missing. im sorry i dont know how to attach image here but i will copy the depedency in node modules
root@db12829f79ed:/app/node_modules/quasar/dist/transforms# ls
api-list.json  auto-import.json  import-map.json  loader-asset-urls.json

i also did a fresh install using 2.14.0, and the contents of dist/transform is also missing the import-transformation.js
root@ea98af96a459:/app/node_modules/quasar/dist/transforms# ls
api-list.json  auto-import.json  import-map.json  loader-asset-urls.json

I don't see how it's possible. Both contain  import-transformation.js. I'd expect you install the latest somehow, check version in node_modules/quasar/package.json
